# Intel 3570k OC's to higher ratios with more stability than 4670k; Any cons to reverting?

Tags: cpu, overclocking

My generous friend recently left me his old PC which included an Intel 4670k. I recently began using software to OC my old PC's 3570k and was thrilled to learn that 5 years into it's life (without previously OC'ing) it could reach a 44x ratio and be stable without a voltage boost (extra volts on any ratio made if perform worse in benchmarks; 45x ratio wouldn't boot under reasonable voltage boosts, so I stopped there). I believe the default voltage on it was 1.024 or 1.04.

Upon receiving my friend's chip and PC, about 3 years old, I noticed that it becomes unstable and blue screens at his BIOS set ratios of 40-42 at a 1.072 voltage. Note that I am keeping the frequency at 100mhz as that worked best for me on the 3570k.

It's possible that my friend has caused damage to the chip from continuous experimental OC'ing, but whether or not that is true, if I cannot optimize the chip to run as fast as the 3570k, is it an obvious choice to bring back the faster clocked chip that is a less prestigious model, or will I be also be losing out on some feature I am unaware of on the newer, 'better' chip, that makes this decision more nuanced?

Answer (score 0):

Intel's CPU are fairly complex devices, and an ability to boot at certain clock multipler is far from full (or good) characterization of a CPU.

These two CPUs are fairly different. The older one (i5-3570K) and newer (i5-4670K) are quite a bit different chips, designed by different teams, and tested/binned/validated differently. The older one runs Intel 4000 graphics at 650 MHz bus rate, while the newer one has 4600 graphics, and memory controllers are different, the older uses regular DDR3, while the newer one uses DDR3L low voltage, which means different drivers. The older uses DMI, while newer uses DMI2 system interface. These are not just incremental differences in design, they are different, and might respond differently to overclocking.

Now, Intel has hundreds and hundreds of production and test engineers who's job is to sort wafer's output and configure CPUs for best performance and stability by proper "fusing" [hint](https://www.quora.com/How-is-a-CPU-core-fused-out). CPUs have dozens of interconnected blocks that must work in unison, and tester's job is find the best combination of functional blocks, local voltages, and interface timings, all within imposed guardbands. Different CPU models may have different tolerance to overclocking.

There are also external factors. You don't know which CPU block did fail during your overclocking. Maybe it was a subtle memory fault? Did you use the same memory? Does the two mainboards have the same trace layout/loading? Maybe the on-board power supplies on your two boards have very different dynamic voltage response, and one of them can't properly keep up with abrupt load changes? Or maybe they have different ripple level, which also narrows the range of overclockability?

It is also not given that an older but overclocked chip has a better system performance than less-clocked newer chip. You need to run many benchmarks to make a distinction, not just "GHz".

Comment: An older overclocked chip may also burn out quicker.